# Increase in carrier concentration on account of passing a current

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, electric-current

I have been told that the carrier concentration in semiconductors increases while a current is passing through it. Is this true? And if it is true, why is it so? Does current passing through a semiconductor increase the density of states? (I'm saying this intuitively judging how tunneling current creates energy levels inside the barrier). The classical picture doesn't make a lot of sense since it would say that current flowing implies that when one particle (read an electron or hole) enters the respective area, the other particle leaves, so there is no charge aggregation, which is Kirchoff's current law in effect. What would be the quantum mechanical reasoning for this, if it is true anyways.

Comment: Take a diode. With no current, there is a space charge region with very low carrier concentrations (not zero, but low). Now, increase the voltage into forward conduction. Now there are lots of carriers in what was the depletion region. Admittedly, electrons and holes flow in from their respective sides only to annihilate each other, but you would not get net annihilation without having excess (non-equilibrium) charges.

Comment: but what if I have a conductor? Would there be an increased density of states in the conductor on account of current? The diode forward current, in my limited knowledge, exists because the forward potential reduces the depletion region width which in turn reduces the reverse dipole moment of the depletion and result in lower opposing drift current resulting in a net statistical diffusion in the direction of the voltage, but does it affect the carrier concentrations on either side of the depletion region?

Comment: In the case of a metal, excess charge would lead to space charge and a net potential. So, no, a metal will not have excess charge. The same holds true in semiconductor regions away from a junction.